# How can I like a post/comment in facebook fan page from my custom website

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-like

I am importing the posts and comments in my FB fan page to my custom website. I am importing using graph api. In the response array I am getting two types of action URL for "comments" and "likes".

See below :

```
http://www.facebook.com/149263441795729/posts/240758399312899
```

Using this link in following code

```
<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/149263441795729/posts/240758399312899" width="450" height="80"/>
```

I get the following error

The page at http://www.facebook.com/149263441795729/posts/240758399312899 could not be reached.

How can I like these posts or comments from my website? Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

I think--I'm no expert here--that redirects such as this are controlled by Facebook, with a cross-site scripting policy file on their servers that say whether or not they will allow redirects and to who.  On my website for example I allow anybody to cross link, since I'm just a little guy, but I bet Facebook only allows it with preferred partners like various corporations, see the story below.  That would be my best guess.

Paul

http://thenextweb.com/facebook/2011/09/15/facebook-may-be-adding-cross-linking-to-foursquare-yelp-gowalla-and-more-on-pages/

Facebook may be adding cross-linking to Foursquare, Yelp, Gowalla and more on Pages

Facebook appears to have added cross-linking between Pages and other location-based sites like Foursquare, Yelp, Gowalla and SCVNGR to its Pages, reports Scribbal. Tech evangelist Robert Scoble posted a notice on his Google+ profile earlier today that  indicated a new partnership between Foursquare and Facebook as the Page for a place was shown to direct viewers to the comparable location on Foursquare.

The links appear off to the left underneath the ‘Like’ count and checkin count on a location’s page. The only question that remains is whether the users are activating these connections themselves or if it is something that is done automatically. This could be Facebook’s plan to integrate itself with other location sites now that it has distributed the Facebook Places features throughout its framework.

Facebook has been on a tear lately, adding the Subscribe button and smart Friends list features just this week, as well as Facebook integration into the new Skype for Mac. It is clearly making an effort to maintain its lead over Google+ as the preeminent social network and it doesn’t want lack of features to be a reason for anyone to quit it.

We have reached out to Facebook about this new feature and will update this post when we hear back.

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for your reply. So you are saying that currently I cant "like" or "comment" on the posts in my website using FB "Like" button right?

Comment: I found a solutions for this but still I am facing an issue.

First I will explain my solutions. I used below code to add "Like" functionality to my page. I used Object Id of the post in href (see below code)

    <fb:like href="149263441795729_240688205986585" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="450" action="like" colorscheme="light" />

But Once I click Like bAutton the post will get liked on FB but the Post To Facebook prompt comes with below URL

**You like http://149263441795729_240688205986585/**

which is an invalid URL.

Any thoughts on this issue????

Comment: Hope you solve this problem Deepak, but I would not be surprised if the problem lies with Facebook and not your code.  Keep us posted.